# Is there a new notification feature for closed votes?

Tags: discussion, notifications

Few minutes a ago, I got a red dot that looks a some new notification feature. I clicked on it and it looked like it was over the *Close Vote* button. It looks almost like the current comment notification one would get when there is a new comment.

[image]

I have few questions:

**1**.Is this a new feature or has it been available for long time. This is the first time I am seeing this.

**2**.Is it only available for the *Close Votes* or is it also available for other *Reopen Votes* and other menues below it?

**3**.When do we see this? Does it appear arbitrarily?

**4**.Is it possible to disable it? I really don't mind keeping it on. Just wondering.

Comment: I see. It's a new feature. From the images and the answer from the dup, #1,#2,#3 are answered but not #4. I guess you can't disable it then....

Comment: It's a new, old feature.  It appeared, went away, then appeared again.  We're all waiting to see if it's there tomorrow.  I can hardly wait.